# Requests go to document root with Apache alias

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, apache2, mod-alias

I have this configurartion

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myserver.fr
    SSLEngine on
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    DocumentRoot /srv/apache2/htdocs/

    Alias /subdomain/ /srv/apache2/htdocs/subdomain/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

When I request https://myserver.fr/subdomain I get the Apache error:

```
File does not exist: /srv/apache2/htdocs/app, referer:https://myserver.fr/subdomain
```

where "app" is a subfolder of /srv/apache2/htdocs/subdomain/

If it's useful, here is the output of apachectl -S:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server myserver.fr (/srv/apache2/conf/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
         port 443 namevhost myserver.fr (/srv/apache2/conf/sites-enabled/default-ssl:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server myserver.fr (/srv/apache2/conf/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost myserver.fr (/srv/apache2/conf/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: the file does not exists complains about documentrootpath not alias path, make sure you are not landing in another 443 virtualhost, thus the alias is not being read.

Comment: @ezra-s I only have one 443 virtual host, since I'm not allowed to have subdomains. I updated my question is the output of apachectl -S

Comment: Where is that "mimove-myserver.fr" defined? it is weird to see apachectl -S mention two names where you just seem to have 1.

Comment: are you sure "/srv/apache2/conf/sites-enabled/default-ssl" is the virtualhost you showed?